Guitar pedal mod - trigger button presses from a microcontroller by shorting the switch contacts?
I have a guitar foot-pedal (Boss RC-300) and in order to do a lot of the navigation and configuration of the pedal I have to keep crouching / bending down to change patches or change settings.
I would like to be able to use an ESP8266 or ESP32 to wirelessly trigger button presses by externally shorting the button contacts, because some of the buttons don't connect to ground and I don't want to try reverse-engineering or risk damaging anything.
Do I need anything special to do this, or could I use a transistor or optocoupler to short two contacts together to simulate a button press? Example circuit (MCU output to switch contacts) would be a bonus so I don't make a stupid mistake.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
EDIT to add circuit suggested by Michal Podmanický

simulate this circuit

can the foot-pedal be controlled over USB connection?

@jsotola Not to my knowledge. It can take MIDI input for performance functions, so I may do that at a later stage - but the general configuration buttons can only be controlled by physically pressing them, and those are the ones I want to control remotely.

If you want to use an opto you need to know how the button is connected anyway because you have to connect its transistor in correct current direction.
Or use two optos with their transistors antiparallel.
Btw, the darlington opto you drawn there will be always 0.7V drop across transistor.
Find whether button is connected to gnd or Vcc is simple. Just measure the resistance between button contacts and Vcc and Gnd also. Only one option should shows a 0ohm.
Edit:
Switching with two optos:


The schematic builder here didn't have a symbol for optocoupler so I improvised the LED/transistor combo. What I meant is, the buttons may be connected between two pins of the pedal's MCU. I could not find a connection to either Vcc or GND on those buttons - so my best bet is to just short the button to simulate a button press. Is it doable with a transistor, if not an optocoupler? Is there another way I can short the switch pins, if not those? (Relay is obviously out of the question due to size constraints)

As I mention using two optos is a solution when collector of first one is connected to emitter of second one and vice versa. To make a switch drive both leds.

Thank you! That helps a lot.
